# How to get bundle product price by product id ? Magento2

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, crontab, cronjobs

In the code below, I get the product price by identifier, but only the first product price is returned for different product id. Can help me ?

```
    public function getBundlePriceByid($product_id){
      $_store = 1;
      $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($_store, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
      $prices = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMaximalPrice()->getValue();
      $this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
      return $prices;

   }
// 1 = 250$
// 7 = 260$
// 8 = 270$
 $prIds= array(1,7,8);
    foreach($prIds as $prId){
        echo $this->getBundlePriceByid($prId);
    }
```

returns only 250$

This code I call in Cron Job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'bundle') {
      $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
      $specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();            
}
```

Here `product_id` is your product Id.

Comment: This code work without cron, but in cron doesn't work

Comment: temper, sorry, it works fine , thank you very much, i replaced get to create